# Why does PowerShell function work in Windows but not Linux?

Tags: powershell

I wrote a couple of PowerShell utility functions to display the components of PATH and PATH-like environment variables to the console on separate lines. They work in Windows, but have unexpected results in Linux.

I put the following functions in my `$PROFILE` file on each system.

```
Function Split-EnvPath {
    param ($EnvPath)

    $EnvPath -split [IO.Path]::PathSeparator
}

Function Show-Path {
    Split-EnvPath $env:Path
}

Function Show-PSPath {
    Split-EnvPath $env:PSModulePath
}
```

All three functions work in Windows, but `Show-Path` doesn't show anything but a blank line on Linux; Typing `Split-EnvPath $env:Path` in the Linux PowerShell command line does what you'd expect it to. I figured out that the value of `$env:Path` is `null`, but I can't guess why. I assume there's something wrong with the script accessing the environment, but why wouldn't `Show-PSPath` have the same issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux is a case-sensitive Operating System. Here "PATH" and "Path" are different.

So instead of "Path", use "PATH".

**Try the below command:**

```
$env:PATH
```

**Read more about Linux case sensitivity here:**

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/why-is-linux-case-sensitive-125995/

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/656005/what-does-case-sensitivity-is-a-function-of-the-linux-filesystem-not-the-linux

Comment: D’oh! I actually knew that, but I foolishly expected PowerShell to work the same in either OS.